# Custom CPT - Programmatically create categories to assign CPT when a new one is created

Tags: php, custom-post-types

I'm creating a CPT using this code in my OOP plugin

```php
        register_post_type( 
            'products',
            [
                'label' => __('Products', ''),
                'description' => __('', ''),
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'rest_namespace' => $this->namespace,
                'public' => true,
                'supports' => [
                    'title',
                    'editor',
                    'revisions',
                    'thumbnail'
                ],
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-store',
                'register_meta_box_cb' => [$this, 'register_product_metabox']
            ]
        );
```

I want to create some categories using the plugin, so I can assign the CPT to a category when a new one is created. How I can achive this?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: at the moment just created manually the categories from wp dashboard. What I want is to have X categories that I can use when a new CPT is created to assign it